# jQuery UI slide animation for both elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'll very appreciate if someone gives solution for the animation "problem" below, when one div appears with animation, others just jump into the new position without any effect:

```js
$("header").on("click", ".click", function(){
        $(".menu").toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300);
    });
```

```css
header{
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
}
  .click{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

main{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
}
  .menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
  }
  .content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
  <div class="click">Click</div>
 </header>
<main>
  <div class="menu" hidden="true">I'm falling from above slowly...</div>
  <div class="content">Why am I jumping?</div>
</main>
```

How to make both divs animate with jQuery UI slide effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to both divs have the same UI effect, you'll to select both. So far you only have .menu.

$(".menu").toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300);

convert to -->

$(".menu, .content").toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300);

**UPD:** I think if you add to css transition: all 1s ease; to content element it would work. Use webkits to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

```
.content {
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't make sense, because I don't need `.content` to be toggled

Comment: I think if you add  to css   transition: all 1s ease; to content element it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you specificaly need jqueryUi for this?

Replacing

```
$("header").on("click", ".click", function(){
    $(".menu").toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300);
});
```

with

```
$("header").on("click", ".click", function(){
    $(".menu").slideToggle(300);
});
```

Should do the trick.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jaw275c3/1/)**

Comment: yeah, it's one of posible optionbut in this case exact "slide" effect loses :(

Comment: I mean when text in div goes down too, not just opens